# Use jquery to trigger event in different bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The page has 4 different tabs, and there is an [exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/VzZJA/978/).

If I click the button on the Home tab, I want to make the paragraph on Menu1 to disappear. I tried to use code like this(which doesn't work):

```
$("hidemenu1").click(function(){
    $("#p1").hide();
});
```

I think you have to refer to the parent to somehow get the id of the paragraph, instead of directly calling the paragraph's id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a simple type-o.

if hidemenu1 is a class, add a . before

if it's an ID, add a #.

```
// if it's a class
$(".hidemenu1").click()

// it it's an ID
$("#hidemenu1").click()
```